# Unable to set colors for lets-plot chart with kotlin

Tags: kotlin, ggplot2, datalore, lets-plot

i am trying to generate a pie chart with lets-plot with Kotlin and i am unable to manually set colors to the sections of the chart. I am using `org.jetbrains.lets-plot:lets-plot-kotlin-jvm:4.4.1` and the image export and Kotlin api dependencies.

Here is a minimal example:

```
val data = mapOf("name" to listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "b"), "value" to listOf(40, 90, 10, 50, 20))

val plot = letsPlot(data) + scaleFillManual(values = listOf("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9","#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
                geomPie(size = 20, stroke = 1.0, tooltips = tooltipsNone)
                { fill = "name"; weight = "value"; slice = "value"}

ggsave(plot, filename)
```

But whatever i do, i get an OutOfBoundsException when using the `scaleFillManual()` function to set the colors of the sections of the pie chart manually..

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0

    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:361)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at jetbrains.datalore.plot.builder.assemble.PositionalScalesUtil.finalizeDomains(PositionalScalesUtil.kt:96)
...
```

I also cannot find any documentation or example which is explaining this feature. I have seen python syntax for this, but there is simply the list in brackets as argument..

Comment: I've tried exactly your code example, and it successfully export a Pie chart using grey, yellowish and blueish colors (tried both svg and html output). Does your error occurs with this exact sample ? What format do you export to ? Also, the error does not seem related to colors, but to the layers of the plot, which, for this to happen, would be empty.